# CodeMirror not updating textarea correctly

Tags: jquery, codemirror

I have multiple instances of CodeMirror on my page inside a jquery-ui tab widget. I create these instances dynamically like so:

```
//Returns a code mirror editor
editor.create = function(id){

    var codeID = "code-" + id;
    var $node = $('<form><textarea id="' + codeID + '" name="' + codeID + '">test</textarea></form>');
    editor.editors[id] = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($node.find("textarea").get(0), editor.options);

    return $node;


};
```

Each instance is stored in a global array called `editors`.

Once it is created, it is appended to the DOM.

```
var $editor = editor.create(id);
var tabID = "tabs-" + id;
var $tab = $('<li id=' + id + '><a href="#' + tabID + '">' + name + '</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span></li>');
var $tabPanel = $('<div id="' + tabID + '"></div>');

$tabPanel.append($editor);

$('#coder > ul').append($tab);
$('#coder').append($tabPanel);
coderTabs.tabs("refresh");
```

The test text placed in the textarea displays in the editor. However, calling `editor.editors[id].save()` does not update the textarea.

```
$('#project-save').click(function(){
        var active = $( "#coder" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
        var id = $('#coder .ui-tabs-nav li').eq(active).attr("id");
        console.log(editor.editors[id]);
        editor.editors[id].save();
        return false;
});
```

I am not sure what step I am missing to get the textarea to update. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I had the wrong concept about how this worked. I added `.save()` to `onBlur` and then when it comes time to do something with the data I call `.getValue()` on the editor instance.